# Fortify - SQL injection issue for dynamic SQL statement

Tags: c#, oracle, fortify

Scenario - in the application we are creating SQL statement dynamically.

```
string query = ”Select {0} from TABLENAME where {1}”;
string.Format(query, columnNames, whereClause);
```

These variable column names are coming from a third party service from our own domain. However, while running the fortify scan for this code, I am getting an error for SQL injection. The message says that the data `columnNames` is coming from the UNTRUSTED service. How do I handle this scenario?

Comment: You've built a solution that depends on doing SQL injection.  You then ran it through a security tool that flagged the fact that you're opening yourself up to SQL injection.  What is it, exactly, that you want to happen at this point?  Are you asking how to design the system so that it doesn't need to do SQL injection?  Are you asking how to tell Fortify to ignore this particular error when it scans the code?  Something else?

Comment: That's where the pain is. It's an existing application. The architecture was designed in this way only. Is there any possible solution to make Fortify understand that the service is a known one, not unknown?

Comment: I have not used Fortify.  There are SO questions, though, that appear to indicate you can create filters to ignore certain errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798596/how-to-exclude-warnings-in-fortify